How to make a Hotspot with Security (Password) for use with KDEconnect
I have a Problem with Hotspots, every time I try to make one, it makes a Hotspot without any Password or Security.
Then I tried to change Password and Name, now every new Hotspot has that Name and Password, but doesn't work.
Is there a way to make a Hotspot with security, for use with KDE connect?
Thanks in advance
